# Installing Search Server Express with local machine accounts?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, setup

Is it possible to install and run SSE 2010 with local accounts instead of domain accounts?

For example: I would use

LOCALMACHINE\SP_FARM instead of MYDOMAIN\SP_FARM

LOCALMACHINE\SP_SETUP_ADMIN instead of MYDOMAIN\SP_SETUP_ADMIN...

... and so forth

The server is joined to the domain but my customer does not want to use Domain-Accounts.

If it's possible, are there any disadvantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install stand-alone version, it could be possible.

But I can't see any reason, why NOT use domain accounts. Maybe customer heard some security rumors. Try to convince him to use domain accounts to avoid problems in future.

We had similar problem to connect sharepoint server to domain, because customer was scared of security issues.